# Highcarts Space between number If the value is exceed 1K

Tags: highcharts

How to remove the space between number in highchart. I tried with pointFormat but It is not working. Please find the below reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Should this be tagged [javascript]?

Comment: Also what is your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [formatting tooltip of the highstock ohlc chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153160/formatting-tooltip-of-values-1000)

Comment: Please refer the below link. https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/ If the value is exceed the 1000 then there will be space between the digits

Answer (score 12):

Please set the `lang.thousandsSep` parameter equal to `""` (empty string value). In order to achieve it you can set that parameter's value globally by `Highcharts.setOptions()`. Here is the code:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
    thousandsSep: ""
  }
})
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/wm87L9zh/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang.thousandsSep

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Isn't this exactly what he needs?

Comment: accept this answer and give @daniel_s the credit, as it helped me.